# <a> that does not have an href, cannot click or get info

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, click, href

I'm trying to use Python/Selenium to iterate through and extract calendar appointment information from a website.

On the web page, clicking this  makes a flyout appear with calendar appointment details:

```
<a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-draggable fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future fc-event-future fc-event-show" tabindex="0" data-calendar-event-1856361581="" data-test-appointment-event="">
```

I'm trying to either get Python to make that flyout appear, or to capture the information `data-calendar-event-1856361581=""`.

Even without making the flyout appear I can get what I need from one of the `<a>` attributes (at least I think it's an attribute?):
`data-calendar-event-1856361581=""`
The `1856361581` portion of that value is the appointment ID and is all I need to create the URL to make the flyout appear, but I cannot figure out any way to capture the `data-calendar-event-1856361581=""` information. Each appointment on the calendar has its own unique appointment ID in `data-calendar-event`, and I'm looping through all of the appointments.

I can find the above  element via XPATH, but `.click` does not make flyout appear:

```
appt_path = 'appt_path = '//table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/div[1]/a''
appt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, appt_path)
appt.click
```

I tried the following to try and find anything for `data-calendar-event-1856361581="` but so far I can't locate it anywhere:

```
print(appt.get_property('attributes')[0])
print(appt.get_attribute('class'))
```

Any assistance in either making the flyout appear or capturing `data-calendar-event-1856361581=""` would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Loop through all the attributes, checking if it begins with `data-calendar-event-`. Then extract the appointment ID after that.

Comment: `.click` should be `.click()`. It's a function, you have to use `()` to call it.

Comment: @Barmar has provided the perfect answer for me. I forgot the () for .click(). This resolved my issue.  Thank you @Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-draggable fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future fc-event-future fc-event-show" tabindex="0" data-calendar-event-1856361581="" data-test-appointment-event="">
```

To extract the attribute name *`data-calendar-event-1856361581`* you can use the `get_attribute()` method as follows:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/div[1]/a').get_attribute("outerHTML").replace("=", " ").split(" ")[13])
```

---

### Proof of concept

Code:

```
outerHTML = '''<a class="fc-timegrid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-event-draggable fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future fc-event-future fc-event-show" tabindex="0" data-calendar-event-1856361581="" data-test-appointment-event="">'''
print(outerHTML.replace("=", " ").split(" ")[13])
```

Output:

```
data-calendar-event-1856361581
```